# Wrong x and y cordinates on 'onclick' event

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Hi, i'm making an simple prototype of app.**
The idea is simple, there are a box, and when you click it, it creates a square that changes the color when you click at it.

The problem is: When i click at the box to generate the square, it generates below the box, and i don't know why.

**Here is the full code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #27293F;
        }
        
        #title {
            width: 100vw;
            height: 20vh;
        }
        
        h1 {
            width: 100%;
            color: #4FFF5A;
            text-align: center;
        }
        
         p {
            width: 100vw;
            color: #379A3D;
            text-align: center;
        }
        
        #plants {
            width: 100vw;
            height: 75vh;
            border: 10px solid #FF5555;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
    
        .plant {
            position: static;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
        }
    </style>
    
    <script src="Plant.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <section id="title">
        <h1>The plant generator </h1>
        <p>click anywhere in the box to generate a plant</p>
    </section>
    
    <div id="plants">
        
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        const colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];
        
        const plantsContainer = document.getElementById('plants');
        
        plantsContainer.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
            generatePlant(event.x, event.y, plantsContainer);
        });
    
        /**
         * Changes the plant's color on click.
         * @param   {Plant}            plant          Target to change the color.
         * @param   {HTMLDivElement}   plantElement   The plant element.
         * @returns undefined
         */
        function changeColorOnClick(plant, plantElement) {
            let index = plant.getState().colorIndex + 1;
            
            index >= colors.length ? index = 0 : null;
            
            plant.setState({ ...plant.getState(), color: colors[index], colorIndex: index });
            
            plantElement.style.backgroundColor = plant.getState().color;
        }
    
        /**
         * Generate a plant.
         * @param   {Number} x         The plant's x cordinate.
         * @param   {Number} y         The plant's y cordinate.
         * @param   {any}    appendAt? The element to append the plant at.
         * @returns {Plant}
         */
        function generatePlant(x, y, appendAt) {
            let plant = new Plant();
            
            x = x ?? Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerWidth);
            y = y ?? Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerHeight);
            
            generatePlantElement(plant, x, y);
            
            console.log(x, y);
            
            return plant;
        }
        
        /**
         * Generate a plant element.
         * @param {Plant}  plant     The plant.
         * @param {Number} x         The plant's x cordinate.
         * @param {Number} y         The plant's y cordinate.
         * @param {any}    appendAt? The element to append the plant element at [optional].
         */
        function generatePlantElement(plant, x, y, appendAt) {
            let plantElement = document.createElement("div");
            let plantState = plant.getState();
            
            plantElement.classList.add("plant");
            
            plantElement.style.marginLeft = `${x}px`;
            plantElement.style.marginTop = `${y}px`;
            
            plantElement.style.backgroundColor = plantState.color;
            
            (appendAt || document.body).appendChild(plantElement);
            
            plantElement.onclick = () => changeColorOnClick(plant, plantElement);
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Plant.js:

```js
window.Plant = class Plant {
    
    /**
     * @param {Object} state? Custom state [optional].
     */
    constructor(state) {
        this.state = state || { color: 'red', colorIndex: 0, waterable: true, watered: false };
    }
    
    /**
     * Changes the plant's state.
     * @param {Object} state Custom state.
     * @returns {Object}
     */
    setState(state) {
        this.state = (state ?? this.state) ?? { color: 'red', colorIndex: 0, waterable: true, watered: false };
        
        return this.state;
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns the plant's state
     * @returns {Object} 
     */
    getState() {
        return this.state ?? { color: 'red', colorIndex: 0, waterable: true, watered: false }
    }
    
    /**
     * Stringify the plant's state.
     * @returns {String}
     */
    toString() {
        return JSON.stringify(this.state);
    }
}
```

I have tried many things like transform, negative y and etc.
But none of them worked right...

Any idea to fix it would be helpfull

Comment: it is because you are appending it direct to `body`.

Comment: and you need to use `position: absolute` for `.plant` and instead of giving `marginTop` and `marginLeft` use `top` and `left` also give it `z-index` greater than `#plants` and set `position: relative` to`#plants`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your js seems fine, it's the css that's tripping you up :)

use position: relative on the #plants div, and position:absolute on the .plants.  then rather than positioning them using margins, use top and left to supply coordinates.

explanation: position: absolute 'lifts' an element out of the normal ordering of elements on a page and positions it on x/y coordinates *relative to* the nearest parent with relative positioning. since you want the plants to appear in a specific area, give that relative positioning, and position the plants absolutely within that relative container.

Sorry, I didn't come up with the names of the position attributes.
see https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

[edit: replaced my abbreviated html with the original entire thing.]

```js
window.Plant = class Plant {
    
    /**
     * @param {Object} state? Custom state [optional].
     */
    constructor(state) {
        this.state = state || { color: 'red', colorIndex: 0, waterable: true, watered: false };
    }
    
    /**
     * Changes the plant's state.
     * @param {Object} state Custom state.
     * @returns {Object}
     */
    setState(state) {
        this.state = (state ?? this.state) ?? { color: 'red', colorIndex: 0, waterable: true, watered: false };
        
        return this.state;
    }
    
    /**
     * Returns the plant's state
     * @returns {Object} 
     */
    getState() {
        return this.state ?? { color: 'red', colorIndex: 0, waterable: true, watered: false }
    }
    
    /**
     * Stringify the plant's state.
     * @returns {String}
     */
    toString() {
        return JSON.stringify(this.state);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
    
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #27293F;
        }
        
        #title {
            width: 100vw;
            height: 20vh;
        }
        
        h1 {
            width: 100%;
            color: #4FFF5A;
            text-align: center;
        }
        
         p {
            width: 100vw;
            color: #379A3D;
            text-align: center;
        }
        
        #plants {
            position: relative;
            width: 100vw;
            height: 75vh;
            border: 10px solid #FF5555;
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
    
        .plant {
            position: absolute;
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
        }
    </style>
    
    <script src="Plant.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <section id="title">
        <h1>The plant generator </h1>
        <p>click anywhere in the box to generate a plant</p>
    </section>
    
    <div id="plants">
        
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        const colors = ['red', 'blue', 'green'];
        
        const plantsContainer = document.getElementById('plants');
        
        plantsContainer.addEventListener('mousedown', function(event) {
            generatePlant(event.x, event.y, plantsContainer);
        });
    
        /**
         * Changes the plant's color on click.
         * @param   {Plant}            plant          Target to change the color.
         * @param   {HTMLDivElement}   plantElement   The plant element.
         * @returns undefined
         */
        function changeColorOnClick(plant, plantElement) {
            let index = plant.getState().colorIndex + 1;
            
            index >= colors.length ? index = 0 : null;
            
            plant.setState({ ...plant.getState(), color: colors[index], colorIndex: index });
            
            plantElement.style.backgroundColor = plant.getState().color;
        }
    
        /**
         * Generate a plant.
         * @param   {Number} x         The plant's x cordinate.
         * @param   {Number} y         The plant's y cordinate.
         * @param   {any}    appendAt? The element to append the plant at.
         * @returns {Plant}
         */
        function generatePlant(x, y, appendAt) {
            let plant = new Plant();
            
            x = x ?? Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerWidth);
            y = y ?? Math.floor(Math.random() * window.innerHeight);
            
            generatePlantElement(plant, x, y);
            
            console.log(x, y);
            
            return plant;
        }
        
        /**
         * Generate a plant element.
         * @param {Plant}  plant     The plant.
         * @param {Number} x         The plant's x cordinate.
         * @param {Number} y         The plant's y cordinate.
         * @param {any}    appendAt? The element to append the plant element at [optional].
         */
        function generatePlantElement(plant, x, y, appendAt) {
            let plantElement = document.createElement("div");
            let plantState = plant.getState();
            
            plantElement.classList.add("plant");
            
            plantElement.style.left = `${x}px`;
            plantElement.style.top = `${y}px`;
            
            plantElement.style.backgroundColor = plantState.color;
            
            (appendAt || document.body).appendChild(plantElement);
            
            plantElement.onclick = () => changeColorOnClick(plant, plantElement);
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: he don't want to plant the plants outside the div `#plants`. Lol there are so many plants.

Comment: @KunalTanwarI I tested the full snippet and the plants go in #plants like OP wants.

Comment: I obviously snipped the the irrelevant parts out to emphasize what I was doing. should I have left the entire thing in?